# Did the Romans pronounce ph like the letter f or the letter p?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation

I'm wondering – how would the Romans have pronounced *ph* if these letters were together in a word like "triumphantes"? Would it be pronounced like the letter *f* or the letter *p*? Did the Romans even ever put *ph* together in a word?

Answer (score 10):

The diagraph *ph* in Classical Latin represents an "aspirated voiceless plosive," which means that it sounds like the *p* in the English word *pot* – a strong *p* sound, with aspiration (if you put your hand in front of your face, you'll feel air when you say it).

*Ph* and its relatives *th* and *ch* were initially used primarily to transcribe Greek names and loan-words, like *Philippus* and *philtrum*, and later entered native Latin words like *triumphus*.

More details are available in *Vox Latina*, by W. Sydney Allen, and in [this related answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/648/12). Allen concludes his treatment of these letters by reminding us that the *ph* certainly did not sound like the *ph* in the English *photo*:

> There is no justification for pronouncing the aspirates as fricatives—i.e. as in *photo*, *thick*, *loch*; this is admittedly the value of φ, θ, χ in Late Greek, but it had not yet developed by classical Latin times.

However, toward the end of the period of Classical Latin, instances of *ph* as a fricative (sounding like English *f*) do begin to appear, as described here: [When did 'ph' start to be pronounced like 'f'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/649/12)