# Is pronouncing 'th' as 's' in 'Boethius' typical in any common Latin pronunciation scheme?

Tags: pronunciation, medieval-latin, consonants

I'm listening to lectures by theologian Douglas Kelly ([*Medieval Theology*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/medieval-theology-dr.-douglas/id592462344), lectures 7 and 8), in which he repeatedly pronounces the name *[Boethius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boethius)* as:

- boh-EE-see-us (how it sounds to me)
- /boʊˈiːsiəs/ (my guess at IPA)

Is there a recognized Latin pronunciation scheme in which the *th* in *Boethius* would be pronounced with an *s* sound?  Vulgar Latin?  Italian or French? Kelly is no stranger to European languages, so I wonder if he might have picked it up in a non-English setting.

It reminds me of a reverse of Spanish, in which *z* in some dialects is pronounced as *th* (θ).  But it's a far cry from Classical Latin, where [*th* represents a voiceless plosive](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/648/12), like the *t* in *top*.  So is this some pronunciation scheme I've never heard of, or just a mistake?

Comment: I guess the θ is harder to pronounce in that place, and s is an easier alternative.

Answer (score 10):

It actually helps to know that the *th* was not always there. A variant of his name that was common (standard?) in Medieval and early modern texts was [Boetius](https://books.google.com/books?id=gJ61nQEACAAJ&dq=boetius&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVko2KxK_TAhXBbiYKHW-ODssQ6wEINjAD). In some texts, he's even [Boece](https://books.google.com/books?id=eaeRoNoGtAUC).

While a standard pronunciation of the former is /boʊˈiʃəs/ ("bow-EE-shiss"), the latter is /boʊˈis/ ("bow-EES"); cf. Statius ("STAY-shiss") and Lucrece ("loo-CREASE").

I imagine that there must have been a tradition in some university that combined the two, and Douglas Kelly is drawing on that.

Comment: /boʊˈiʃəs/? Where did the "-iu-" go?

Comment: @IllidanS4 The *i* softened the *t*, and thus lost a distinct pronunciation on its own.

Comment: ʃəs is closer to "shuss" than "shiss".

Comment: @OrangeDog: It depends on if one has the weak vowel merger. For speakers who do, non-word-final /ə/ is often realized with greater vowel height than the phoneme /ʌ/. For me, /ʌ/, /ɪ/ and /ʊ/ all seem approximately equally close to non-final /ə/.

Answer (score 5):

We need to distinguish a mediaeval *Latin* pronunciation from an *English* one.  The English pronunciation is what would be used in talking about him in a English context, and is what one might expect for "Boëthius" [boʊˈiːθiəs] ("bowEEthius") The alternative spelling "Boëtius" yields [boʊˈi:ʃəs] ("bowEEshus") or similar.

*However*, if one wants to know how he and his contemporaries pronounced his name, it was probably [boˈeːtsiʊs] ("boAYtsioos")

Explanation:  The name is of Greek origin and would contain a theta in Greek.  If one were to pronounce this in the Classical way, that would be [bo'e:t(h)iʊs].  By late Latin times, however, "th" was pronounced exactly like "t" (which is why "Boetius" is a mere spelling variant of the "correct" "Boethius"), and moreover the sequence [ti]+vowel when unaccented came to be pronounced [tsi]+vowel.  Thus, [boˈeːtsiʊs] for Boet(h)ius.

This assibilated "t" would further develop, often to [s] in many areas speaking a neo-Latin dialect, and in particular France.  And, after the Norman Conquest, French conventions for pronouncing Latin were imported into England.  Thus, Latin *natio* went from Classical [natio:] to late [natsio] to French *nation* (with "t" pronounced [s]).  The last step is to further assimilate [sj] to [ʃ] as in English "nation".

In summary, [th] -> [t] and [ti] -> [tsi] in late Latin; [ts] -> [s] in French; and [sj] -> [ʃ] in English.

Oh yes, forms like "Boece", "Stace", and "Lucrece" are French forms, imported into English.